# How to display terms & conditons the right way?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, frame

I have a label beside a checkbox for accepting terms & conditions. At the moment there is a simple

`<a href="/termns.php">Terms</a>`

where an user can read the terms.

More comfortable would be using jQuery to add a grayed-out box on the same page.

To give more information I am using a multiple language site. In fact it would be possible to create one File with all the text in every language version but this file would get pretty much confusing.

That's why I did a workaround to that problem and use templates to get the right version. In the matter of a Session setting there will be a redirect into the right directory. So the main textfile is placed in `/language/terms.php` where the template will be included once.

Now I played around and found something like this:

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#popup_terms').click(function(){ 

        $("#screen").css({
            "display": "block",
            "width": $(document).width(),
            "height": $(document).height(),
            opacity: .7,
        });

        $("#screen-box").css({
            "display": "block",
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<label for ="tandc"><?php echo $signup_tac;?></label>
<div id="screen"></div>
<div id="screen-box">
    <?php include_once "../$language/popup_$filename.php";?>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#screen{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    border: none;
    background: black;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#screen-box{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 500;
    display: none;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 600px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 25%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This seems to be not the correct way because when having a look into the source code the text from the terms will be visible, what I do not wonder about.

So what would be a "right" way to handle this issue?

Comment: take a look for this link... http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/03/simple-jquery-modal-popup-window-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try ajax or an iframe if you don't want the source code in your page right away.

Assuming the path ../$language/popup_$filename.php is accessible by the user's browser, the solutions are the following.

**The iframe way**

```
<label for ="tandc"><?php echo $signup_tac;?></label>
<div id="screen"></div>
<div id="screen-box">
    <iframe src="<?php echo "../$language/popup_$filename.php"?>"></iframe>
</div>
```

**The AJAX way**

HTML :

```
<label for ="tandc"><?php echo $signup_tac;?></label>
<div id="screen"></div>
<div id="screen-box"></div>
<script>window.termsUrl = '<?php echo "../$language/popup_$filename.php"?>';</script>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#popup_terms').click(function(){
        $("#screen-box").load(window.termsUrl, function(){
            $("#screen").css({
                "display": "block",
                "width": $(document).width(),
                "height": $(document).height(),
                opacity: .7,
            });

            $("#screen-box").css({
                "display": "block",
            });
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. i tried the ajax way and still have a problem with that line: `var termsUrl = '<?php echo "../$language/popup_$filename.php"?>';` it does not seem to generate the php script so it does not work with that but when adding the URL by hand it works and it will fetch the file the right way.

Comment: You may try to define the variable in the HTML. I have edited the example with that change.

Comment: Alright, thats it. Now it works as should be. Thanks alot for your help! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use a jquery ui dialog. you just need to set the container and associate to dialog , then you just need to call open or close methods using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the JQuery UI Dialog plugin or something like FancyBox. Saves time and headaches. These plugins load content with AJAX so you wouldn't need to include the content on the first pageload, which could be a problem when you want to use more boxes like this.